# Using js to make rest request on html onclick

Tags: javascript, html, rest

I almost always work with python so all this is new-ish to me. Here I am in the early stage of building a web app with a simple login page. I am trying to make it so that when I click the login button, the onclick action in the html should call the `login_user` function to make a rest request to the backend api I already built.

Heres the html and js function:

```
<div>
    <label for="username">username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="password">password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
</div>

<button id="loginButton" onclick="login_user()">login</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function login_user(path, username, password) {
        'http://127.0.0.1:5000/' = path;
        document.getElementById('username') = username;
        document.getElementById('password') = password;

        let data = {username: username, password: password};

        return fetch(path, {method: "GET", body:                 
            JSON.stringify(data)});
    };
</script>
```

However, this won't make a request. I dont think the issue is within the javascript? I've tried to make a more simpler function that would simply redirect me to the homepage at the onclick but that wouldnt work either. I am not too sure what is going on and if you could point me in the right direction that would be amazing!

Comment: You can look at the browser console for errors by pressing `F12`

Comment: @Rust ah yes. got this: Uncaught ReferenceError: login_user is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick -- not sure because login_user is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>
<div>
    <label for="username">username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="password">password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" minlength="8" required>
</div>

<button id="loginButton" onclick="login_user()">login</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
function login_user() {
    let path = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resource";
    let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    let data = {username: username, password: password};

    fetch(path, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"},
            method: "POST", 
            body: JSON.stringify(data)}
    );
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/");
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function login_user(path, username, password) {
        'http://127.0.0.1:5000/' = path; // Assigning values is wrong.
...
}
```

You have to rewrite the function as:

```
function login_user() {
        let path = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/';
        let username = document.getElementById('username');
        let password = document.getElementById('password');

        let data = {username: username, password: password};

        return fetch(path, {method: "GET", body:                 
            JSON.stringify(data)});
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Is syntax error !
    'http://127.0.0.1:5000/' = path;
Login function, for security, you should use POST method.

See more about fetch api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: please provide detail answer instead of adding link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it seems you are getting undefined for the input values

```
function login_user(path, username, password) {
    path = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/';
    username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    let data = {username: username, password: password};

    return fetch(path, {
        method: "GET", 
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
};
```